# IIS binding and throughput, how do they work?

Tags: web-services, iis, networking

A consultant at work mentioned that you can have web services running on different endpoints and hence utilize the network correctly if I have more than one network card with different bandwidths.

Not being too network savvy, is he saying I can take my web service and tie it down to one network card and make sure clients make calls at that network card to access it as I have more bandwidth at that card?

Can I do this without changing the clients?

Also if my web service has a number of web methods and I want some web methods to run on a different network card, would I have to split the web service so that the web methods are on different web services? In other words I would have to write two web services?

Answer (score 1):

Are you really maxing out your network that you need to implement something like this? I would look into bottlenecks within the application first before going down this road.

If your network is the bottleneck, then perhaps moving you web service to a completely different server might be a better solution. It'll mostly likely be cleaner and easier to implement.

Having said that, it can probably be done, but would be convoluted. Network cards would need to be on different networks. Wouldn't make sense if it's the same network. Each network card will have different IP address assigned.

In IIS, you'll need to make sure that site which houses your web service is configured for one particular IP address.

> Can I do this without changing the clients?

Depends. You will need to make sure whoever is calling your web service does it using the IP address configured within IIS. That might mean either creating a DNS record that points to that particular IP address OR editing your clients to point to the right IP address.